# How to generate oauth token, client id and secret using gcloud or Google Cloud Java SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, cloud, gcloud

I have a very big task, I need to automate the process of creating Dialogflow agents, for which I need to first create a Google project, which I have figured out using Java SDK, then I need to get client id and client secret to get an access token to send it to Dialogflow agent creation REST call, I just don't know how to generate a Oauth credentials for a project.

I'm using Java, Play framework. I even got success creating service account but just can't figured out how to generate Oauth creds.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You cannot create "Client ID / Client Secret" except by using the Google Cloud Console. Creating client secrets and using OAuth are two different topics.

Comment: I mean when you generate oauth credentials, you get client id and client secret but generating oauth credentials can not be automate, it always require user interaction with the cloud console GUI, like setting up oauth consent screen. I just need a way to get client id and client secret, with which I can generate bearer access token using goole oauth library, and pass it to REST agent creation call.

Comment: From your previous comment I understand that you want to get a service account key which contains the client id, project id, private key, etc. right?

Comment: No, I need to get clientId and client secret, in google console we get it from credentials => oauth client id => select other, enter name => generates clientId and secret. I want to automate this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after doing some more research, turns out there is no API or there is no way to create oauth credentials clientId and client_sercret / client_secret.json file programmatically. One has to create it from google console itself.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to call a Google API (Dialogflow) one is via a service account.

You mention you have already [created a Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount).

Next you can automate the credential creation via the [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) as mention [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests).

Finally just call the Google API

You can find the full documentation of DialogFlow for Java [here](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/index.html?com/google/cloud/dialogflow/v2/package-summary.html)

Comment: Yes, I understand there are various methods of calling google api's like API key, service account, oauth, but the problem is creating an agent REST call https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/agent?apix=true requires to send access_token, which can only be generate using clientid and client secret, and client_secret.json is generated after settting oauth creds in your project.
heree's the java code to to generate access_token for REST call but it requires client_secret.json file.